# Validation error does not display for a select field with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In running a Rails 3.2.11 with nested_form gem with formtastic support, the validation error message does not display for the *f.select* helper below the select field when there's an error.

If I change f.select to *f.input*, the error then does display below the field.  Is this a bug or does Rails does not automatically inject errors for a validation on a select field?

I've basically fixed it by tapping into the "Model".errors.messages helper provied by Rails, but it results in some custom if/else logic I'd like to avoid.  I'd rather have Rails automatically inject the `*<p class="inline-errors">some error message</p>*` if possible.

**model.rb**

```
validates :consultant, :presence => { :message => "consultant is missing." }
```

**form.html.haml**

```
= semantic_nested_form_for @agreement, :url => "/agreements/update", :html => { :class => "agreement", :autocomplete => "off" } do |f|
  = f.select :consultant, options_for_select(["","option1","option2"], @service_agreement.assigned_consultant)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with your select options. My bet is that "" is considered as present. What you want is to have a blank option in the select box instead.

```
= f.select :consultant, options_for_select(["option1","option2"], @service_agreement.assigned_consultant), include_blank: true
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the empty quotes and used include_blank but that didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: Could you try and check whether the validation fails for the form with select? Pass it a proc and raise an error or something similar. I believe that consultant is present, hence no validation.